# parameter is not received in method

Tags: objective-c, methods, parameters

I have a method which is simple and quite forward. 
It is supposed to create a folder if it doesn´t exist.
It takes one string parameter which is properly declared.

When I use it and pass a parameter the receiving variable remains empty which is pretty strange because pathTo_Folder is a path.

Any ideas why this happens?

```
//Declaration in .h
- (void) createFolder         : (NSString *) thePath  ;

//The call
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSString *homePath = [@"~" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
    NSString *pathTo_Folder = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Library/Application Support/prolog/",homePath];
    [self createFolder : pathTo_Folder];
}


//In .m
- (void)    createFolder: thePath {
    BOOL isDir;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager]         ;
    [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:thePath isDirectory: &isDir]          ;

    NSLog(@"Folder '%@' exists: %d",thePath,isDir)                      ;

    if (isDir == FALSE) 
    {
        [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath: thePath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you think `thePath` should have a type?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that since you don't define the type of `thePath`, the compiler defaults it to an `int`, and an `int` doesn't print very well with `%@`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, 
I copied the definition from the .h to the .m Like this: 
- (void) createFolder : (NSString *) thePath  ; 
and now it works. 

Thanks a lot.
 
Ronald
---

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any type declaration for the argument `thePath` selector, it should be

```
- (void)    createFolder:(NSString*)thePath {
    BOOL isDir;
```

Probably you don't get a warning because it has a default to `id` but that will mostly solve the issue. But an `id` type would be ok in this case, maybe it's some ObjC black magic..

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit cleaner and should work:

```
- (void) createFolder: (NSString *) thePath;

- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching: (NSNotification *) aNotification
{
    NSString *appSupportDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory,
  NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    [self createFolder: [appSupportDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"prolog"]];
}

- (void) createFolder: (NSString *) thePath 
{
    BOOL isDir;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: thePath isDirectory: &isDir]) {
        [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath: thePath withIntermediateDirectories: YES attributes: nil error: nil];
    }
}
```